# Работа с базой данных в отдельном потоке qt

Tags: sql, qt, многопоточность, qml

У меня есть класс-обертка для базы данных. И есть класс-обертка для модели, в которую из базы данных записываются результаты `query` запроса. К этой модели я обращаюсь из `qml` слоя. Мне нужно реализовать объекты этих классов в отдельном потоке. Я написал такой код:

```
main() 
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QThread *thread = new QThread();

    DataBase *database = new DataBase();
    ListModel *model = new ListModel();

    database->moveToThread(thread);
    model->moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), database, SLOT(connectToDataBase()));

    thread->start();

    qDebug() << "thread " << thread;
    qDebug() << "engine " << engine.thread();
    qDebug() << "current " << QThread::currentThread();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", model);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("database", database);

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

И в каждом из классов есть функции, которые выводят в консоль поток в котором они выполняются:

- thread  QThread(0x1bf10c98)
- database 0x1bf10c98
- engine  QThread(0x1c0677b8)
- current  QThread(0x1c0677b8)
- listmodel  QThread(0x1bf10c98)

Как видим, все выводится так, как мне и надо. Но прога зависает на некоторое время, когда я отправляю `query` запрос.

В чем ошибкa?

Comment: А в каком потоке осуществляется непосредственно подключение к БД? Если это производится в конструкторе `DataBase`, а затем объект класса переносится в другой поток, то это неправильно.

Comment: Я это знаю. QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), database, SLOT(connectToDataBase())); В конструкторе я не подключаюсь.

Comment: A query (запрос) просто на выборку из таблицы? И выполняется ли этот запрос в том же потоке, где и существует подключение? СУБД также укажите в вопросе.

Comment: Да, запрос тросто на выборку. Там просто база огромная. Запрос выполняется в том же потоке(я поместил list model в поток, а запрос выполняется в list model). СУБД - SQLite

Comment: А параллельных каких-нибудь запросов к этой же БД нет из главного (gui) потока в тот момент, когда выполняется выборка в `list model`? Возможно, что gui "морозится" по причине длительной блокировки БД при выполнении "тяжёлого" запроса. Также, причиной тормозов может являться тот факт, что представление (view) и модель располагаются в разных потоках. Например, виджетные view это очень не любят.

Comment: Ну у меня весь интерфейс в qml. И там list view действительно в другом потоке. Если это причина, то как ее решить? Паралельных запросов нет.

Comment: Я в qml не силён, но скорее всего `QQmlApplicationEngine` создаёт какой-нибудь класс-адаптор в gui потоке и который в свою очередь подключается к модели, вызывая её методы напрямую. Естественно это приводит к проблемам. Если не существует способа каким-то образом этот класс-адаптор перенести в поток к `list model`, то наверное единственным выходом является переопределение функционала `list model` таким образом, чтобы запрос отправлялся в требуемом потоке, обрабатывался потокобезопасно ответ, а сама модель при этом обязательно должна находиться в gui потоке.

Comment: Но интерфейс подвисает даже если я вывожу, например, количество строк в этой модели. И я не думаю что в этом проблема.

Comment: Не стану спорить, но никто не мешает провести эксперимент. Уберите многопоточность из кода и потестируйте вызовы методов модели однопоточно.

Comment: Так и было. Результат с многопоточностю и без, один и тот же.

Comment: Пробуйте тогда ограничивать выборку. Предполагаю, потому как из вопроса не ясно, от какого класса модели наследуется `ListModel`. Если от sql-класса, то там есть поддержка докачки данных по необходимости (т.е. берётся не весь массив данных сразу), а если от модели, реализующей обычный список, то пагинация целиком и полностью ложится на плечи автора кода.

Comment: ListModel наследуется от sql-класса

Comment: Тогда минимальный компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Дальнейшее гадание теряет смысл, т.к. по основным ситуациям прошлись.